# grabbing url link to then store in a variable to send to async

Tags: php, android, json

Pretty simple question, but I am quite new to java and still not quite sure how JSON works. I have a JSON on a restful service here: (http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True) my app then runs through each and grabs the course number for each course which then creates a new json with the course number that i grabbed from the original json, example would be here: (http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/36-1600?json=True). This is already done no need to go more into it. My confusion now lies on how to grab the URL from the 2nd link I gave you you will see a string "Images" with a bunch of urls after. I just want to grab the first URL for each JSON it goes to (I just posted 1 example, the reason I put the other info at the start was for this exact reason, if you look at the first link each course will have a number, so that number is then set in this format: (http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/XX-XXXX?json=True)

Really just a basic question, although I think it was necessary to post that paragraph since I have gotten help in the past that has led me far astray where my assignment was supposed to be. I am just trying to get the first link so I can then do an Async to put that url in an imageview I have. Here's what I have tried/attempted so far (String Images is what I have added, everything else already works.

```
first = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firsttv);
        second = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondtv);
        third = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thirdtv);

        String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        System.out.println(id);

        String response = readBuilding(id.trim());
        System.out.println(response);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
            if(jsonObj.length()>0)
            {
                String CourseName = jsonObj.getString("CourseName");
                String CourseNumber = jsonObj.getString("CourseNumber");
                String CourseDescription = jsonObj.getString("CourseDescription");
                String Images = jsonObj.getString("Images");

                first.setText("CourseName:- "+CourseName);
                second.setText("CourseNumber:- "+CourseNumber);
                third.setText("CourseDescription:- "+CourseDescription);

            }
```

Also before people have replied with "oh you don't have a catch in there" or "oh you didn't close your class" Please refrain from answering with those suggestions, I only post the code that's necessary to my question. I am well aware I need a catch and to end the class! Thank you in advance.

EDITS:

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
            if(jsonObj.length()>0)
            {
                String CourseName = jsonObj.getString("CourseName");
                String CourseNumber = jsonObj.getString("CourseNumber");
                String CourseDescription = jsonObj.getString("CourseDescription");
                JSONArray arrayOfImages = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Images");

                int arrSize = arrayOfImages.length();

                List<String> urlOfImage = new ArrayList<String>(arrSize);

                first.setText("CourseName:- "+CourseName);
                second.setText("CourseNumber:- "+CourseNumber);
                third.setText("CourseDescription:- "+CourseDescription);
                for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i)
                {
                    jsonObj = arrayOfImages.getJSONObject(i);
                    urlOfImage.add(jsonObj.getString("Images"));
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image info isn't a String, your JSon have an array of string's in this property, so you need first start to get an array of objects then you can get your first string.

```
JSONArray arrayOfImages= json.getJSONArray("Images")
```

Now you can get your image first string....

Comment: json. <-- eclipse doesn't like this. I created a JSONObject jsonObj is that what you meant? (tried it in eclipse and it removed the error).

Comment: change json to jsonObj :) that's your current object looking at your code

Comment: Ghost, I tried some stuff, put it in my edits, am I on the right track?

Comment: @user3380292 yeah, you are doing fine... try to print your JSonObject (in your for) so you will understand better how to get your image url